# [Slurm]Changing the order of jobs when using the Builtin scheduler type

Tags: slurm

Basically, I want to let the system follow FIFO, but sometimes I want to change the priority of jobs by the administrator.

This is why I set the `scheduler type to builtin`, but in that case, I could not change the order of jobs using the `scontrol top` command.

I also tested the `backfill scheduler type` with `default_queue_depth=0` option but it isn't worked.

If anyone have a good idea, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this issue by using `scontrol hold` and `scontrol release` Command.  The hold status takes precedence over the `builtin scheduler type`　setting.